# Spawn an .obj or .stl file in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn, stl, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently got a couple models that I would like to import into gazebo. However they are of .obj and .stl file types (I have each model in both formats). Is there a direct way to import these models into Gazebo? Do I need to convert them to something else first?

I've made simple models out of boxes for Gazebo by writing raw xml files using commands like

> rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file
> my_path/fridge.xml -gazebo -model Fridge -x 0 -y 1 -z .4 -Y 3.14159

However using this command and replacing -gazebo with -urdf just throws errors like

> SpawnModel: Failure - model format is

or

> GazeboROSNode SpawnModel Failure: input model_xml not Gazebo XML, or cannot be converted to Gazebo XML
> not URDF (nor COLLADA).

Clearly obj and stl are not the correct formats for these commands, so how is it done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32022/spawn-an-.obj-or-.stl-file-in-gazebo/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fridge.xml needs to be in either urdf, [gazebo sdf in Fuerte](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/sdf_format) or [gazebo model format in Electric](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-0.5-html/worldfile_syntax.html).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2012-04-18**:
I've made models in those formats before, but I was hoping I could use regular models, like .obj or .stl. However form what you've said it sounds like that's not possible, which sucks :(

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-18**:
for static models where dynamics/collision is not important, this might be a feature request on the gazebo side,  can you open a feature request ticket with details of behavior you'd like to see on  https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/newticket?  thanks!